# oscillatory integrals in one dimension

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let$$K_{a,b}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\psi({\xi})\xi^{-b}e^{ix\xi\pm \xi^{a}}d\xi}\quad a,b>0$$
where $\psi\in C^{\infty}$, equals to $0$ when $\xi<\frac{1}{2}$, and equals to $1$ when $\xi>1$.

As far as I know, when $0<a<1$, $a=1$,and $a>1$,the behaviors of $K_{a,b}$ are quite different (for proper choice of $b$, the singularity lies in $x=0$,$|x|=1$, $x=\infty$ respectively). I want to know the reason behind this and I also want to know how to evaluate such kind of integrals.

Comment: With this assumption on $\psi$, it's not a continuous function.

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the $\psi$ function and just make the integral from 1 to $\infty$?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're trying to evaluate
$$
K_{a,b}\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{\infty} dy \ y^{-b} \exp\left(i x y\right) \exp\left(\pm y^a\right)
$$
for $a,b > 0$?

Comment: @Davide Giraudo：sorry,I have fixed it

Comment: @ Eric Angle:right,it's essentially what you have written down.